# How to read output of hexdump of a file?

Tags: c++

I wrote a program in C++ that compresses a file.

Now I want to see the contents of the compressed file.

I used hexdump but I dont know what the hex numbers mean.

For example I have:

`0000000 00f8`
`0000001`

How can I convert that back to something that I can compare with the original file contents?

Comment: Primarily, what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Have a read here http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/asciiBin.html

Comment: erm, `man hexdump`? But looking at the contents of the compressed file is meaningless - decompress and then diff - that will tell you whether both works...

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a file containing the single byte `0xf8`. I say that since it appears to have the same behaviour as `od` under UNIX-like operating systems, with the last line containing the length and the contents padded to a word boundary (you can use `od -t x1` to get rid of the padding, assuming your `od` is advanced enough).

As to how to recreate it, you need to run it through a decryption process that matches the encryption used.

Given that the encrypted file is that short, you either started with a very small file, your encryption process is broken, or it's incredibly efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you implemented a well-known compression algorithm you should be able to find a tool that performs the same kind of compression and compare its results with yours. Otherwise you need to implement an uncompressor for your format and check that the result of compressing and then uncompressing is identical to your original data.